# TypeError: Assignment to constant variable, when trying to create an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I've been working on a scraper and all was good until I've tried to push objects of scraped data into an array.

Right now I have this:

```
exports.parseData = (getLink, getDescription, getPrice, getPicture) => {
  const apartments = [];
  apartments = {
    link: getLink,
    descr: getDescription,
    price: getPrice,
    picture: getPicture,
  };
  console.log(apartments);
};
```

But it throws an error: `TypeError: Assignment to constant variable`.

Now I think this is happening because of how data is sent to a parser.
Here is how data looks when I use this code:

```
exports.parseData = (getLink, getDescription, getPrice, getPicture) => {
  console.log(getLink);
  console.log(getDescription);
  console.log(getPrice);
  console.log(getPicture);
  console.log('-----------------');
};
```

```
https://www.sant.ba/nekretnine/nekretnina-3467-dvosoban-stan-sa-liftom-u-samom-centru-grada-63-m2
 dvosoban stan sa liftom u samom centru grada , 63 m2 
199000.00
https://www.sant.ba/thumb.php?file=photos/3467/3467_1_1563271355.jpg&maxw=273&maxh=205
-----------------
https://www.sant.ba/nekretnine/nekretnina-3689-troiposoban-stan-u-naselju-sunca
 Troiposoban stan u naselju Sunca
360000.00
https://www.sant.ba/thumb.php?file=photos/3689/3689_1_1612344465.jpg&maxw=273&maxh=205
-----------------
https://www.sant.ba/nekretnine/nekretnina-3677-trosoban-renoviran-stan-u-naselju-dolac-malta-73-m2
 trosoban, renoviran stan u naselju Dolac malta, 73 m2
150000.00
https://www.sant.ba/thumb.php?file=photos/3677/3677_1_1608550332.jpg&maxw=273&maxh=205
-----------------
https://www.sant.ba/nekretnine/nekretnina-3537-cetverosoban-stan-u-novogradnji-sa-prelijepim-pogledom-na-grad-118-38-m2
 Četverosoban stan u novogradnji sa prelijepim pogledom na grad, 118,38 m2 
538090.37
https://www.sant.ba/thumb.php?file=photos/3537/3537_1_1573217155.jpg&maxw=273&maxh=205
-----------------
https://www.sant.ba/nekretnine/nekretnina-3536-trosoban-stan-u-novogradnji-sa-prelijepim-pogledom-na-grad-105-34-m2
 Trosoban stan u novogradnji sa prelijepim pogledom na grad, 105,34 m2
478817.70
https://www.sant.ba/thumb.php?file=photos/3536/3536_2_1573216638.jpg&maxw=273&maxh=205
-----------------
https://www.sant.ba/nekretnine/nekretnina-3535-luksuzni-cetverosoban-stan-na-cobaniji-117-43m2
 Luksuzni četverosoban stan na Čobaniji,117,43m2
533772.19
https://www.sant.ba/thumb.php?file=photos/3535/3535_13_1573215220.jpg&maxw=273&maxh=205
-----------------
https://www.sant.ba/nekretnine/nekretnina-3534-trosoban-stan-u-novogradnji-90-m2
 trosoban stan u novogradnji, 90 m2
376923.46
https://www.sant.ba/thumb.php?file=photos/3534/3534_8_1573214216.jpg&maxw=273&maxh=205
-----------------
etc....
```

Now what my desired output would be: To have an array of objects, where objects are filled with data like it's shown in example above. So for each `getLink, getDescription, getPrice, getPicture` create new object and push it into an array(like I'm using it in the first code block).

Output that I would like to get is:

```
[
   {
   
      link: https://www.sant.ba/nekretnine/nekretnina-3467-dvosoban-stan-sa-liftom-u-samom-centru-grada-63-m2
      descr: dvosoban stan sa liftom u samom centru grada , 63 m2 
      price: 199000.00
       picture: https://www.sant.ba/thumb.php?file=photos/3467/3467_1_1563271355.jpg&maxw=273&maxh=205
   },
   {
     link:https://www.sant.ba/nekretnine/nekretnina-3689-troiposoban-stan-u-naselju-sunca
     descr: Troiposoban stan u naselju Sunca
     price: 360000.00
     picture: https://www.sant.ba/thumb.php?file=photos/3689/3689_1_1612344465.jpg&maxw=273&maxh=205
   },
   etc...
]
```

Is something like this easy to achieve?
Thanks!

Here is from where these variables are sent:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');
const parsing = require('./parseData');

exports.olxScraper = () => {
  const url =
    'https://www.olx.ba/pretraga?vrsta=samoprodaja&kategorija=23&sort_order=desc&kanton=9&sacijenom=sacijenom&stranica=1';

  const getRawData = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get(url).then((res) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
        $('div[id="rezultatipretrage"] > div')
          .not('div[class="listitem artikal obicniArtikal  i index"]')
          .not('div[class="obicniArtikal"]')
          .each((index, element) => {
            $('span[class="prekrizenacijena"]').remove();
            const getLink = $(element)
              .find('div[class="naslov"] > a')
              .attr('href');
            const getDescription = $(element)
              .find('div[class="naslov"] > a > p')
              .text();
            const getPrice = $(element)
              .find('div[class="datum"] > span')
              .text()
              .replace(/\.| ?KM$/g, '')
              .replace(' ', '');
            const getPicture = $(element)
              .find('div[class="slika"] > img')
              .attr('src');

            parsing.parseData(getLink, getDescription, getPrice, getPicture);
          });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  getRawData();
};

exports.santScraper = () => {
  const url = `https://www.sant.ba/pretraga/prodaja-1/tip-2/cijena_min-20000/stranica-1`;

  const getRawData = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

        $('div[class="col-xxs-12 col-xss-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4"]').each(
          (index, element) => {
            const getLink = $(element).find('a[class="re-image"]').attr('href');
            const getDescription = $(element).find('a[class="title"]').text();
            const getPrice = $(element)
              .find('div[class="prices"] > h3[class="price"]')
              .text()
              .replace(/\.| ?KM$/g, '')
              .replace(',', '.');
            const getPicture = $(element).find('img').attr('data-original');
            /*const getSquaremeters = $(element)
        .find('span[class="infoCount"]')
        .first()
        .text()
        .replace(',', '.')
        .split('m')[0];

      const pricepersquaremeter =
        parseFloat(getPrice) / parseFloat(getSquaremeters);
      articles[index] = {
        id: getLink.substring(42, 46),
        link: getLink,
        descr: getDescription,
        price: Math.round(getPrice),
        pictures: getPicture,
        sqm: Math.round(getSquaremeters),
        ppm2: Math.round(pricepersquaremeter),
      };*/
            parsing.parseData(getLink, getDescription, getPrice, getPicture);
          }
        );
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(console.log(error));
    }
  };
  getRawData();
};

this.olxScraper();
this.santScraper();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a constant, the reference cannot be changed. In your code it says `const apartments = []`, so you declare const as an array and later try to declare const as an object.

Try

```
apartments.push({
    link: getLink,
    descr: getDescription,
    price: getPrice,
    picture: getPicture,
  });
```

Comment: Tnx for the answer. But it doesn't work as I expect it. It's returning me: array with object. array with object array with object etc.. Instead of just one array with multiple objects inside it

Comment: @pupeeterMaster if you want one array, you can declare this array outside of this function and send it like argument, or this function return a object that will pushed in array, example const `const apartment = {//properties}`

Answer (score 0):

There are more than just one issue with your code:

1. You can't reassign a [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) variable.

   ```
    const apartments = [];
    apartments = { ... };  //this is not allowed, becasue apartments is const.
   ```
2. You define `apartments` as an array, and then try to assign an object to that same variable. That's allowed in javascript, but probably not what you want ...

**EDIT**

As for your comment: If you want a single array to contain all your objects, you must define your array outside of your function and define your `parseData` function to return an object, which then can be pushed into that array.

```
const apartments = [];
const getRawData = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get(url).then((res) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
        $('div[id="rezultatipretrage"] > div')
          .not('div[class="listitem artikal obicniArtikal  i index"]')
          .not('div[class="obicniArtikal"]')
          .each((index, element) => {
            $('span[class="prekrizenacijena"]').remove();
            const getLink = $(element)
              .find('div[class="naslov"] > a')
              .attr('href');

            ....

            //push the result of parseData into the array
            apartments.push(parsing.parseData(getLink, getDescription, getPrice, getPicture));


           //if your parsedata just returns an object created from its parameters,
           //you can get rid of the function and just do 
           //apartments.push({
           //  link: getLink,
           //  descr: getDescription,
           //  price: getPrice,
           //  picture: getPicture           
           //});
          });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Redefine `parseData` to just return an object. Although it seems quite unnecessary, to have a function which just returns an object of its parameters.

```
exports.parseData = (getLink, getDescription, getPrice, getPicture) => {
  const apartment = {
    link: getLink,
    descr: getDescription,
    price: getPrice,
    picture: getPicture,
  };
  return apartment;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But it doesn't get me back output like a was expecting it to. It returns me array with object one after one, overriding itself, instead of getting just one array with multiple objects inside it.

Comment: If you want all objects to be added into a single array, you'll have to define that array in the outer scope (ie, where you call the function) and either pass the array into the function or return just an object and add that result of the function to the array

Comment: I've updated my desired output. What would your suggestion be? What would be most clear and readable. Note that have more than one scraper where I will be putting my data.

Comment: @pupeeterMaster See updated answer. If you have more than one scraper, you'll have to find some global state, where you can create your array so that all of the scrapers can access it

Comment: I'm bit confused right now. How i would output my apartments then? And also I'm sending data from this component to parseData component. So my data is sent from this scarping component to parseData, where I need to handle my data and insert them into an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring apartments with const.

```
const apartments = [];
```

So it's been set as an array. But then you are then trying to change it to an object.

```
apartments = {
    link: getLink,
    descr: getDescription,
    price: getPrice,
    picture: getPicture,
  };
```

Consts cannot be updated or declared. Once you have declared it as an array. it can only stay as an array. You can push to that array but you cannot change it to an object or any other data type.

In your case, you could just declare the const apartments as an object straight away.

```
const apartments = {
    link: getLink,
    descr: getDescription,
    price: getPrice,
    picture: getPicture,
  };
```

You can read more about var, let and const here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

adding an example based on the comments.

```
const data = [];

const parseData = (getLink, getDescription, getPrice, getPicture) => {
    const apartments = {
        link: getLink,
        descr: getDescription,
        price: getPrice,
        picture: getPicture,
      };
    data.push(apartments)
    console.log(data);
};
```

**data** is not scoped to the parseData function, and can therefore contain all the apartments objects, that get pushed to it. Where this **data** array should be declared depends very much on your code, and should probably be passed to the parseData function as an argument as well.

Comment: Thank you, and I completely understand your answer. But I think you didn't understand me what I'm trying to achieve. Right now that is returning me a object after object without `,` so it's overriding each other and I don't want that.

Comment: I think I understand your problem. You need to declare an array outside of the parseData function, and push your apartment objects to it.

Comment: yep. I need somehow to for each this four variables, create object with key:value pairs, and push all of the objects inside of an array, so from where I will be passing them into the validation component and later to the database.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that you assigned the variable `apartments` as an array and declared it as a constant. Then, you tried to reassign the variable to an object.

When you assign the variable as a `const` array and try to change it to an object, you are actually changing the reference to the variable, which is not allowed using `const`.

```
const apartments = [];
  apartments = {
    link: getLink,
    descr: getDescription,
    price: getPrice,
    picture: getPicture,
  };
```

The options I see as simplest are to push the object into the array:

```
apartments.push({
    link: getLink,
    descr: getDescription,
    price: getPrice,
    picture: getPicture,
  });
```

Or to assign the object to a variable always when you are about to push to the array:

```
const apartments = [];
let apartment = {
    link: getLink,
    descr: getDescription,
    price: getPrice,
    picture: getPicture,
  };

apartments.push(apartment);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that doesn't give me the expected output. With this solution, I'm getting [ {} ] [ {} ] etc. So I have each array overriding, rather than having one array with objects inside it.